# mysql - I want to count from two tables then use the totals to divide

Tags: mysql

I created two tables. One for employees and the other for stores. I want to count the total employees on the employee table and also count the total of stores on the stores table. Since I know there are less stores than employees, I want to get the total from employees and then divide it by the total of stores. To get an average of employees per store.

This is what I have, and it ain't working.

SELECT COUNT (employee_id) from employees / COUNT(store_id) from stores;

Thanks in advance for any help I get.

Answer (score 1):

You need two selects for the counts respectively, and to wrap them in another select for the division.

```
SELECT a.count / b.count as employees_per_store
FROM (SELECT COUNT(employee_id) count FROM employees) a, 
     (SELECT COUNT(store_id) count from stores) b
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM employees) employees, (SELECT count(*) FROM stores) stores
```

Comment: It works, but I was trying to get the average of employees per stores. Thank you none the less.